# How do we handle changing questions after the fact?

Tags: discussion

[Why am I seeing in 3d?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136412/why-am-i-seeing-in-3d)

The problem wasn't with Stanley in specific, or even something as specific as the source engine. This was just the first 3D game I played after 8.1 installation. Should We update the tags and stuff to help more people, or just leave the question as is?

Answer (score 5):

If, after researching the question, it can be determined that the original tags were unintentionally incorrect, it may be in the question's best interests to update tags and/or title.

I am less willing to endorse a changing of the question body, to make it fit the answer.

Comment: You could generalise the tags but make minimal changes to the body, still mentioning the specific game(s) affected, etc, no?

Comment: @kalina Exactly. The important thing (in my book) is to not remove references to the original combination that triggered the whatever, since those same references might help others find the answer.

Comment: The combination that triggered it was installing windows 8.1 and a 3d app (which includes anything source engine, but also would have affected unreal engine, or world of Warcraft or whatever)

Comment: @McKay Right. It is okay to have a *specific* combination, if it can easily be identified as a more *general* problem.

Comment: Yep. If the original question had suspected the system instead of the game, it would have *still* been useful and right to include the game as part of the full context. As it was, the game was suspected and the system was included only as extra context (which is why we encourage extra context!). There's no need to expunge the game from the body, since now it simply reads as extra context. Getting rid of the tag is good though since it's not really about TSP2013 (and is not of specific interest to other TSP2013 players).